# How to have a variable h1..h6 element in Angular components?

Tags: angular

Currently I'm using an `ngSwitch` to produce header HTML elements based on a variable, but it is awfully verbose and simply superfluous:

```html
<container-element [ngSwitch]="headerLevel">
    <h1 *ngSwitchCase="h1">{{ value }}</h1>
    <h2 *ngSwitchCase="h2">{{ value }}</h2>
    <h3 *ngSwitchCase="h3">{{ value }}</h3>
    <h4 *ngSwitchCase="h4">{{ value }}</h4>
    <h5 *ngSwitchCase="h5">{{ value }}</h5>
    <h6 *ngSwitchCase="h6">{{ value }}</h6>
</container-element>
```

Is there a better way? `<{{headerLevel}}>{{ value }}</{headerLevel}}>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by the other answer, the following works quite nicely:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="'<'+headerLevel+'>'+'value'+'</'+headerLevel+'>'"></div>
```

Comment: @Vega then you will get invalid HTML as a `span` element cannot contain the `h1`-`h6` elements according to [the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (specifically, the "content model" of span states it can only contain phrasing content, which does not include the hX elements).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind wrapping the header element in a div this will work
Or you can capture the parent with a ***viewchild*** and append to that using ***Renderer***

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent {

  public headerLevel = 'h1';
  public value  = 'Dynamic Content';

  constructor() {
  }

  getElement() {
    return `<${this.headerLevel}>${this.value}</${this.headerLevel}>`
  }
}
```

**Html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="getElement()">
</div>
```

Comment: Would `<div [innerHTML]="'<${headerLevel}>${value}</${headerLevel}>'">` work? Or `<div [innerHTML]="'<'+headerLevel+'>'+'value'+'</'+headerLevel+'>'"></div>`?

Comment: Answering my own question: indeed it does!

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is from React world. For Angular, better approach is to use directives:

```html
<h1 myAwesomeDirective></h1>
```

Thus, it can extend the needed functionality.

Moreover, it can be [projected](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) and selected within other components:

```html
<ng-content select="[myAwesomeDirective]"></ng-select>
```

For example, take a look how [Angular Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) expects a h1-h6 with a mat-dialog-title directive:

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
```